# Sprite kit bad access swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I need to change sprite texture. I do it like this, but sometimes(not always) I get bad access when changing the texture. I also tried setNeedsDisplay/setNeedsLayout, but that doesnt help Anyone had same problems?

```
    let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Details")
    let texture = atlas.textureNamed("Detail_\(detailType.rawValue)")
    self.texture = texture
```

Comment: Does the app crash? If it does then the problem isn't with setting the texture. Can you post the rest of your code, specifically the parts with detailType.rawValue.